# Reference terraform resource by variable

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I created tf file that takes input from cli and then use this as name for aws lambda, and api gateway.

Currently inputing different name just replace name in currently working one.

My goal is that every time i input new name new lambda and gateway should be created. Is it possible?

```
variable "repo_name" {
 type = string
}

resource "aws_lambda_function" "lambda" {
 function_name = var.repo_name
 handler       = "lambda_function.lambda_handler"
 runtime       = "python3.9"
 role          = ""
 filename      = "python.zip"
}
```

Comment: No, you would have to restructure your code in such a way that when you add a new value terraform just adds a new resource instead of replacing the current one. That means probably changing the variable to a list or a map plus `count` or `for_each` meta-argument.

Answer (score 3):

This can be done in a couple of different ways, but the easiest one would be creating a local variable and just add additional names to it whenever you need a new function and API Gateway. That would look something like this:

```
locals {
  repo_names = ["one", "two", "three"]
}
```

Now, the second part can be solved with `count` [1] or `for_each` [2] meta-arguments. It's usually a matter of preference, but I would suggest using `for_each`:

```
resource "aws_lambda_function" "lambda" {
 for_each      = toset(local.repo_names)
 function_name = each.value
 handler       = "lambda_function.lambda_handler"
 runtime       = "python3.9"
 role          = ""
 filename      = "python.zip"
}
```

You would then follow a similar approach for creating different API Gateway resources. Note that `for_each` has to be used with sets or maps, hence the `toset` built-in function [3] usage. Also, make sure you understand how `each` object works [4]. In case of a set, the `each.key` and `each.value` are the same which is not the case when using maps.

---

[1] https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/meta-arguments/count

[2] https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/meta-arguments/for_each

[3] https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/functions/toset

[4] https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/meta-arguments/for_each#the-each-object